# Autofilter by date (text type) with a conditional statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter a column which has a date in text format, e.g. "*`07/12/2012`*"
I need to autofilter the column34 with a conditional statement:

If the date in each cell is less than the current date +15, select the row.

I am getting empty results after running the following code, ie no rows are selected. Has anyone an idea as of why?

```
With srcSheet
   srcEndRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   .Range("A2" & ":BU" & srcEndRow).AutoFilter Field:=34, Criteria1:="<>NULL", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & Format(Date, "0") 
End With
```

Comment: The last part of your code should have been ` ... Criteria2:="<" & Format(Date +15, "0")` As it stands you are just filtering for the entries before the current date.   I tested this and it worked for me.